# Swapping Inlines (and dynamic Model creation)

Tags: python, django

A game, and lets say there are different (restrictive) settings for recreation and I want to adjust via django admin.

models.py:

```
class Board(models.Model):
     name = CharField()

class Player(models.Model):
     bord = Foreignkey('Board')
     max_cards = IntegerField()

class Card_Slot(models.Model):
     owner = Foreignkey('Player')
     card = CharField()
```

A Board should have a random number of Players associated with it. An inline `TabularInline` should be used to add or delete Players, with an `IntegerField` for the max number of Cards (`max_cards`).
I use signals on save to create dynamically Card_Slots appropriate to the number of max_cards.
 --- thats what I have, now what I want ---
'Swapping' the Inline after setting the `max_cards`, for an Inline that represents the Players and their Cards (thus Playername and card in Card_Slot should be editable).

---

Several headaches come up for me on that. If possible I don't want to overwrite admin templates. If I should, I would appreciate a hint that goes further then pointing to the docs, meaning pointing in a direction on good practice.

I'm also not sure, if I should use one Model for Player and Card_Slot. (This would make the edit name thing easier, but the dynamic size of Card_Slots worse).. I think.

I have no clue on how I should do that. Pls help.

(One approach appears to be with custom Fieldsets, which I didn't get to work so far. The thought is to replace the content and type of the Integer Field with a ModelMultipleChoiceField related to a queryset of the Card_Slots. But I dont understand how I can do custom Fields on an Inline without a model etc.)